# WPF: ListViewItem equivalent for DataGrid

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid, row

I have some code that does

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="XX" Value="true" />
</Style>
```

This works as expected on ListViews. However I want to replace the ListView with a DataGrid, and having trouble finding the equivalent of a ListViewItem for the Datagrid. At first thought I expected Datagrid items to inherit from ListView, so that nothing had to be changed, but the Setter had no effect. Then I changed it to:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="XX" Value="true" />
</Style>
```

But it had also no effect. And DataGridItem or DataGridViewItem does not exist, so i'm running out of options. So, what TargetType do I need?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change with the style? How is row displayed or something else?

Comment: No I watch changes to that property, so that I can autoload it's data in the background using data virtualisation.

Comment: @Joshua DataGrid's are UI Virtualized by default, which means the DataGridRows get re-used, and not re-created. Perhaps you should show a more specific code sample of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Rachel Use this (http://www.devzest.com/blog/post/WPF-Data-Virtualization.aspx) code for the Datagrid. Everything works when I call .Load from the _LoadingRow event manually. But I'm trying to mimic the behaviour of the example showed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set generic styles on `DataGridRow`, `DataGridColumn` or `DataGridCell`. Which one you use depends on what setter you are setting.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

</DataGrid>
```